# Function to calculate the sum of 1's in numeric vector gives a wrong result

Tags: r

I want to calculate the number of 1's in a numeric vector. here is my code, It should be 4 but It's 9, there is something wrong with it.

```
data <- c(1,1,0,0,2,2,1,0,1)
num <- function(x){
n <- length(x)
for (i in 1:n) {
if(x[i]==1) sum1 <- sum(i)
}
return(sum1)
}
num(data)
```

Comment: `i` does not reflect the values of your data, it reflects the index, so `sum(i)` is not going to give you the right answers. You would need to figure out how to make use of `x[i]` in calculating the sum.

Comment: "If(x[i]==1)" gives the data as c(T,T,F,F,F,F,T,F,T), I don't know how to calculate the number of "T".

Comment: for this 'simple' task, you shouldn't be using a loop, just do `sum(data == 1)`

Answer (score 5):

There seem to be a few misunderstandings in the code and I'm not sure how to give a lesson on correction other than example. The short and best R solution to your stated problem would be:

```
sum( data == 1 )
```

This works because `data == 1` converts to 1 for every `TRUE` value and 0 for every `FALSE` when you attempt to treat logicals as numbers. If you don't just want a solution to the described problem but your code fixed up something like the following would work.

```
num <- function(x){
  n <- length(x)
  sum1 <- 0
  for (i in 1:n) {
    if(x[i]==1) sum1 <- sum1 + 1
  }
  return(sum1)
}
```

However, for a long vector that function will be spectacularly slow in `R`. Turning the solution I proposed at the beginning of this post into the function would just be.

```
num <- function(x) sum( x == 1 )
```

This function will be very fast for any vector `R` can hold in memory.

Answer (score 0):

```
data <- c(1,1,0,0,2,2,1,0,1)
num <- function(x){
  n <- length(x)
  sum1<-0
  for (i in 1:n) {
    if(x[i] == 1){
      sum1<-sum1+1
    } 
  }
return(a)
}  

num(data)
```

Result:

```
[1] 4
```

You appear to be using the sum operator incorrectly, But all you appear to be returning is the index of the last occurrence of `1`. What I believe is happening is you are overwriting `sum1` every time with the sum of i and 0, and then returning it at the end, if you swap the last two elements in the vector you then get `8` out using your method.

My code I split the if statement and explicitly wrapped its components and used a left assignment operator like the increment function.

I'm sure there's a way to do it more directly, but this way is in my opinion a bit more legible and easier to follow.